# VST3 SDK: Problematic construction of std::string member in ClassInfo object causes program to crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vst

### The Problem:

I'm trying to use the VST Hosting utilities included in the SDK to load a plugin. The code is as shown:

```
#include "vst/v3/Vst3CommonIncludes.h"

int main()
{
    std::string vst3_module_path = R"(C:\Program Files\Common Files\VST3\Kontakt.vst3)";
    std::string error;
    std::shared_ptr<Module> vst_module = Module::create(vst3_module_path, error);
    std::vector<ClassInfo> class_infos = vst_module->getFactory().classInfos();;

    assert(error.empty());
    assert(class_infos.size());

    ClassInfo plugin_info = class_infos[0]; //Crash
    //... load the plugin and do more things
    return 0;
}
```

where `Vst3CommonIncludes.h` just includes all the VST SDK headers from `pluginterfaces/vst` and `public.sdk/source/vst`
8

In my case, the SDK comes in source and cmake files to build them into a static library. So my code and SDK code share the same compiler.

[VST SDK sources from Steinberg Media](https://www.steinberg.net/vst3sdk)

---

### Investigation Done:

My investigation showed that `PluginFactory::classInfos()` returned corrupted data, trying to assign from them causes `std::bad_alloc` since the size of `std::string` is not valid.

Definition of PluginFactory::classInfos() in VST SDK:

```
PluginFactory::ClassInfos PluginFactory::classInfos () const noexcept
{
    auto count = classCount ();
    Optional<FactoryInfo> factoryInfo;
    ClassInfos classes;
    classes.reserve (count);
    auto f3 = Steinberg::FUnknownPtr<Steinberg::IPluginFactory3> (factory);
    auto f2 = Steinberg::FUnknownPtr<Steinberg::IPluginFactory2> (factory);
    Steinberg::PClassInfo ci;
    Steinberg::PClassInfo2 ci2;
    Steinberg::PClassInfoW ci3;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (f3 && f3->getClassInfoUnicode (i, &ci3) == Steinberg::kResultTrue)
//------------Unexpected behaviour here--------------------
            classes.emplace_back (ci3);                //--
//---------------------------------------------------------
        else if (f2 && f2->getClassInfo2 (i, &ci2) == Steinberg::kResultTrue)
            classes.emplace_back (ci2);
        else if (factory->getClassInfo (i, &ci) == Steinberg::kResultTrue)
            classes.emplace_back (ci);
        auto& classInfo = classes.back ();
        if (classInfo.vendor ().empty ())
        {
            if (!factoryInfo)
                factoryInfo = Optional<FactoryInfo> (info ());
            classInfo.get ().vendor = factoryInfo->vendor ();
        }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

After the in-place construction of the new ClassInfo element, `ClassInfo::data::category` and other `std::string` members (name, vendor, etc.) reads `<NULL>` in debugger.

Stepping into the constructor of `std::string`, I've found the `this` pointer during construction of `data.category` is NOT equal to `&data.category`, and was offset by 4 bytes.

```
&data.category = 0x 0000 009b 546f ed14
this (std::string constructor scope) = 0x 0000 009b 546f ed18
//Actual address varies but the offset remains the same
```

Thus the string object became corrupted and later crashes the program.

### Additional Information:

---

#### std::string related experiment:

Also, experimenting with `ClassInfo` and its string members, I ran into this:

```
ClassInfo ci;
ci.get().category = "testCategory";                  //OK
const_cast<string&>(ci.category()) = "testCategory"; //Crash, Access violation at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I think it's highly related to the problem, but I couldn't come up with an explanation.

#### C++ standard consistency:

I also added

```
#if __cplusplus != 201703L
#error
#endif
```

to every relevant file, so I'm sure they share the same STL implementation, the problem will still occur.

#### Reproducing Attempt:

I hoped to recreate a minimal scenario where VST SDK is *not* included, and with my own `MimicClassInfo` that resembles the structure of original `ClassInfo` in some aspects. The problem does not occur.

---

##### Compiler and SDK info:

MSVC 14.37.32822 , using C++17 standard.
VST SDK 3.7.8 build 34 (2023-05-15)

Comment: Note that this question, and the curation actions that have been taken on it, [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426189/10871073).

Comment: So much complaints and noise on meta, but it still lacks of the information about how the static library and the code are built and a compliable [mcve] ignoring the missing dependencies . Why not attempt to build them with the enabled  address sanitizer?

Comment: `ci.get().category = "testCategory"; //OK` - here you use inline `get()` implemented in the header file, hence it is compiled in your code. `const_cast<string&>(ci.category()) = "testCategory"; //Crash, Access violation at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` - here you call `category()` that is not inline and implemented in the library. This is a clear sign of the ABI incompatibility. Maybe mixing 64 bit and 32 bit object files.

Comment: @273K Thanks for coming back hand helping, the ABI argument makes a lot of sene. I'm checking in this direction now.

Comment: Are you using a debug build of the SDK with debug build of your code, and release for release?

Comment: @273K Mixing 32- and 64-bit object files/libraries would almost certainly cause a **linker** error with MSVC. Not a run-time issue.

Comment: @273K And in VisualStudio `__cplusplus`  is useless.. unless certain flag  is enabled (somehow calling it noncompliant). But mismatching versions of compiler used to build app and .dll may cause issues with offsets which would be similar to ODR breach. Using it as a check for template library doesn't work because Microsoft doesn't use that flag that way (they consider it equal to 1)

Comment: You should check the compiler flags provided to 3rd-party library and to your application. Sometimes different keys affect the ABI. I mean if the Meta's code is right, then the only reason of the issue are different compiler settings

Comment: Another reason of this issue is different object size depending on context. Many years ago I've found that the size of the pointer to the member function of the forwarded class is larger than the size of the pointer to the same method but already declared class. The difference in size caused the issues like you presented

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if following is a reason of the issue you're experiencing, but I believe it worth to check it too. Who knows.

The issue I found a couple of years ago is that the size of the member function pointer in VS is different based on context:

- In case if you take the size of the member function pointer for the forwarded class, you get 24 (on 64-bit platform)
- In case if you take the size of the member function pointer for the declared class, you get 8

Because of that in the x86 assembly compiler used invalid offsets to read/write the data for the data members in the class where member function pointer is used. So, sometimes to read for example `std::string field1_;` compiler used offset 8, sometimes it used 32. So that my field had been initialized at address 8 and read from address 32 (which is a data of another field). To figure that out one had to read x86 assembly.

Following is a minimal example of the code to reproduce the issue. It is still actual on vs2022.

```cpp
/// @file 2.cpp
class X ;

size_t foo() noexcept { return sizeof(void (X::*)()); }
```

```cpp
/// @file 1.cpp

// cl 1.cpp 2.cpp

class X {};

size_t foo() noexcept;
size_t bar() noexcept { return sizeof(void (X::*)()); }

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << "\n";
    std::cout << bar() << "\n";
}
```

If you compile and run this app, you get 24 and 8.

How can it affect your app. Let's assume you have `struct X` and `struct Y` which encapsulates the pointer to the member function of `struct X`.

```cpp
/// @file X.h

#pragma once

struct X{};
```

```cpp
/// @file Y.h

#pragma once

#include <string>

struct X;

struct Y {
    void (X:: * field1_)();
    std::string field2_;
};
```

And you have two translation units main.cpp and 2.cpp

```cpp
/// @file 2.cpp

#include "X.h"
#include "Y.h"

#include <iostream>

void foo(Y&y) noexcept {
    std::cout << y.field2_ << "\n";
}
```

```cpp
/// @file main.cpp

#include "Y.h"

void foo(Y& y);

int main()
{
    auto y = Y{};
    y.field2_ = "Hello world";
    foo(y);

}
```

Now if you compile and run this app, it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason of such behaviour is different compiler flags (especially macros) used to build the C++ files.

For example if some `class X` conditionally (based on some macro) defines one more additional data member, that affects the data members layout. If you compile two C++ files one with the macro and another one without that macro, your application may crash if those two C++ translation units work on the same object of `class X`.

So your C++ code can be syntactically correct, but because of different compiler flags, linker may build buggy app.